# Screen capture (sorta) in Flash

Tags: flash, actionscript

I am looking for a way to create and display up to 200 stage screen shots. Currently I record each screen shot in a BitmapData object, then play through all of them. This approach works but it takes too much memory - crashes some browsers.

What is the best approach to solve this problem? Can I create .png's, .flv movie or somehow compress BitmapData?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the content you are shooting? Can't you rebuild it easily in a more "vector" mode?

Comment: Even if you can convert them to a png, you're still trying to display data with a very large memory footprint. Perhaps only loading some at a time (pagination) or even rethinking if Flash is the right tool for the job...

Comment: Can't convert to vector but thinking that compiling FLV might be the best option. Few examples http://www.undefinedcreations.com/Blog/?p=9 and http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/simpleflvwriteras-as3-class-to-create-flvs/.

Answer (score 2):

There more than one solution, but you can try one ot this (and combine):

- make a lower resolution screencapture (scaling, see below)
- transform your BitmapData into a ByteArray (via BitmapData.getPixels()) and call ByteArray.compress() (lossless compression)
- compress image to [JPEG ByteArray](http://www.bytearray.org/?p=775) and defining the quality ratio depending number of capture you will do, resolution of it and memory space available (I'm not sure you can know, this last one) - I think it's one of the better way
- Make a full size for the first one and for the rest, capture only changes and position (see how FlashPlayer debugger feature "Show Redraw Region" work)
- if you working on an Air app, save BitmapData in temporary files
- if it's possible, ask the user to unlock to a large amount of space for LocalSharedObject and write your data inside

Here, a sample code to make a capture with a scale ratio (ex: 100x200 DispObj -> 50x100 BitmapData)

```
var displayObject:DisplayObject;
var scale:Number = 0.5;
var bounds:Rectangle = displayObject.getBounds(displayObject);
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(uint((bounds.width + 0.5) * scale), uint((bounds.height + 0.5) * scale), true, 0);
bitmapData.draw(displayObject, new Matrix(scale, 0, 0, scale, -bounds.x * scale, -bounds.y * scale));
```

Comment: Thanks @mems! I will try this solution, will let you know how it works.